# Something similar to Scala worksheets for C++?

Tags: c++, scala

Is there anything out there that's similar to Scala worksheets? If not, I want to implement it, and would like advice on where to start.

Comment: Could you explain what Scala worksheets are for those of us who don't know Scala?

Comment: It's a feature of the Scala IDE (Eclipse) where users can write code and the return result of each line of code is displayed next to it.

Comment: I guess this is really complicated stuff. Maybe you're interested in [cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling)...